# Is there a way to add JSR303-annotations to cxf-generated classes?

Tags: java, jaxb, bean-validation

The title probably said it all, I was wondering if one could tell the cxf-codegen-plugin to add, for example, the xsd-patterns as `@Pattern` annotations. Schema validation is nice and all, but sometimes I just want to check a single element and not endless myriads of xml lines.

Therefor I was wondering if there is a trick / option / dirty hack out there that would help me turning

```
<xs:simpleType name="string2000">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="2000"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}-[ \t\r\n]][\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}-[\t\r\n]]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

into

```
@Pattern(regexp = "\\p{IsBasicLatin}\\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}-[ \\t\\r\\n]][\\p{IsBasicLatin}\\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}-[\\t\\r\\n]]*")
@Size(min = 1, max = 2000)
```

since adding it manually is a no-go with this amount of xml, and it would really make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no direct experience with the cxf-codegen-plugin but, I too had a need to include `@Pattern`, `@Size`, and other `<xs:restriction />` annotations derived from XSDs into my JAXB generated classes and ended up using the krasa-jaxb-tool which does just this.

See [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan)'s answer in [including-xsrestrictions-as-annotations-in-moxy-generated-java-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396482/including-xsrestrictions-as-annotations-in-moxy-generated-java-classes).

Comment: Sorry that this took so long, other things came up, I'll take a look into it :)