# including xs:restriction(s) as annotation(s) in moxy generated java classes

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, xsd, moxy

I have some new `xsd schema` version updates for which I need to generate corresponding java classes. In the past, I understand that the classes where always generated using EclipseLink's Moxy JAXB implementation and I can see that if the schemas contained `<xs:restriction/>` patterns such as `<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]"/>`, then the corresponding java classes would be generated with `@Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]", message= "...")` annotations in them.

When I use Moxy in my setup to generate these java classes, the classes are generated okay but without the @Pattern annotations in them. I am not too familiar with JAXB and I am wondering what I may be missing to allow for these annotations to be derived from the schemas and inserted into the java classes themselves automatically.

I am not too sure if this is because I am not using a new enough version of Moxy (currently using 2.1.2 version of EclipseLink) which allows for these annotations to be automatically created or, whether previously another tool was used for inserting these annotations into the classes.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Regards,
PM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**Generating Classes**

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) includes the XML Schema to Java Compiler (XJC) from the [**JAXB reference implementation**](http://jaxb.java.net/).  Currently the XJC tool does not have a built in mechanism to generate [**Bean Validation (JSR-303)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) annotations in the model.

**XJC Extensions**

I have not tried the following extension myself but it looks like it may do what you are looking for.  As XJC is very extensible there may be other plug-ins available as well.

- http://code.google.com/p/krasa-jaxb-tools/

**Current Versions of EclipseLink**

> I am not too sure if this is because I am not using a new enough
>   version of Moxy (currently using 2.1.2 version of EclipseLink)

The current version is EclipseLink 2.4.1 and can be obtained from the link below.  It contains new extensions such as [**JSON binding**](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html).

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: Hi Blaise, your suggestion to use the krasa-jaxb-tools plugin was a good one, it does exactly what I was looking for. Took me a while to get it running as a plugin within Xjc but it is now working great. Thanks for your help!